# How to insert values of a matrix in another large and empty matrix

Tags: r, matrix

Sorry in advance for my mitakes, I am new in R.

I have frequency transitions matrices of behavioural sequences of different sizes that i would like to compare. So I decided to sum all the behavioural sequences found in all different matrices in order to buil a general matrix. Now I would like to insert the values of a matrix into this general matrix, like this:

1 - General matrix:

```
   A    B    C    D    E    F
A
B
C
D
E
F
```

2 - A matrix with values:

```
    A    C    F
A   0    0.2  0.1
C   0.1  0    0
F   0    0.3  0
```

3 - New matrix:

```
    A    B    C    D    E    F
A   0    0    0.2  0    0    0.1
B   0    0    0    0    0    0
C   0.1  0    0    0    0    0
D   0    0    0    0    0    0
E   0    0    0    0    0    0
F   0    0    0.3  0    0    0
```

So I tried a little script but it does not work.

```
####
Tab=read.table("XX.csv", header=T, sep=";")
Tab_matrix = as.matrix(Tab);
Tab_col=read.table("Column.csv", header=F, sep=";");
rownames(Tab_matrix) <- Tab_col[1:125,1];

####
Tab_final=read.table("XX_Final.csv", header=T, sep=";");
Tab_matrix_final = as.matrix(Tab_final);
Tab_col_final=read.table("Column_Final.csv", header=F, sep=";");
rownames(Tab_matrix_final) <- Tab_col_final[1:2682,1];
Tab_matrix_final[is.na(Tab_matrix_final)] <- 0

####
y1 <- list(cbind(Tab_matrix),cbind(Tab_matrix_final));
library(data.table)
y2<- rbindlist(lapply(y1, as.data.table), fill = TRUE);
y2[is.na(y2)] <- 0
storage.mode(y2) <- "numeric"
d <- as.data.frame(y2)
```

Answer (score 0):

#### If I understand your question:

- You want to populate your general matrix, let's call it `result_matrix`
- with the data in `smaller_matrix` where the row and column names match
- the rest of `result_matrix` should be populated with zeros

If that's correct then:

#### Assuming your smaller_matrix has data like this:

```
smaller_matrix <- as.matrix( read.table( header = TRUE, 
                                         text = '    A    C    F
                                                 A   0    0.2  0.1
                                                 C   0.1  0    0
                                                 F   0    0.3  0') )
smaller_matrix

    A   C   F
A 0.0 0.2 0.1
C 0.1 0.0 0.0
F 0.0 0.3 0.0
```

#### To solve this you can:

1) Pre-create your `result_matrix` = all zero numeric matrix with row+column names you define.

For example:

```
column_names <- LETTERS[1:6]
row_names    <- LETTERS[1:6]
result_matrix <- matrix( as.numeric(0.0), 
                         nrow=length(row_names), 
                         ncol=length(column_names), 
                         dimnames = list(row_names, column_names) )
```

2) Then, by matching on row names and column names, you can simply:

set result_matrix <- smaller_matrix 
...where   result_matrix rows == rownames(smaller_matrix) 
.....and result_matrix columns == colnames(smaller_matrix)

```
result_matrix[ rownames(smaller_matrix), colnames(smaller_matrix)] <- smaller_matrix

result_matrix

    A B   C D E   F
A 0.0 0 0.2 0 0 0.1
B 0.0 0 0.0 0 0 0.0
C 0.1 0 0.0 0 0 0.0
D 0.0 0 0.0 0 0 0.0
E 0.0 0 0.0 0 0 0.0
F 0.0 0 0.3 0 0 0.0
```

This only updates the matching rows and columns.  The remaining positions stay zero, as you wanted.